# Web scraping python to csv file problems

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Please , i want to get table of information "Meilleurs buteurs par édition" into csv file i try this code but csv file it seems empty and output is the first table not the table that i need some one to help me please ![image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import  requests
import  pandas as pd
URL='https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_buteurs_de_la_Coupe_du_monde_de_football'
results=[]
response = requests.get(URL)
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

#print(soup)
#table= soup.find('table')
table = soup.find("table")
tbody=table.find("tbody")
#table = soup.find("table", {"class":"wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"})
#table = soup.find("table", {"class":"wikitable sortable alternance jquery-tablesorter"}).tbody
#print(table)
rows=table.findAll('tr')
columns=[v.text.replace('\n', '') for v in rows[0].find_all('th')]
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
for i in range (1,len(rows)):
    tds=rows[i].find_all('td')
    if len(tds)==6:
        values = [tds[0].text,tds[1].text,tds[2].text,tds[3].text,tds[4].text,tds[5].text]
    else:
        #for i in range(7):
           # df = df.append({'columns': i}, ignore_index=True)
       values=[td.text for td in tds]
    df = df.append(pd.Series(values), ignore_index=True)

    print(df)

print(columns)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A'])
for i in range(5):
    df = df.append({'A': i}, ignore_index=True)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'test': results})
    df.to_csv('but.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Output
Rang Joueur Équipe  ...     3       4     5
0   NaN    NaN    NaN  ...  24\n  0,67\n  16\n
1   NaN    NaN    NaN  ...  19\n  0,79\n  15\n
2   NaN    NaN    NaN  ...  13\n  1,08\n  14\n
3   NaN    NaN    NaN  ...   6\n  2,17\n  13\n
4   NaN    NaN    NaN  ...  14\n  0,86\n  12\n
5   NaN    NaN    NaN  ...   5\n   2,2\n  11\n
6   NaN    NaN    NaN  ...  17\n  0,65\n  11\n
7   NaN    NaN    NaN  ...  10\n     1\n  10\n
8   NaN    NaN    NaN  ...  12\n  0,83\n  10\n
9   NaN    NaN    NaN  ...  12\n  0,83\n  10\n
10  NaN    NaN    NaN  ...  13\n  0,77\n  10\n
11  NaN    NaN    NaN  ...  16\n  0,63\n  10\n
12  NaN    NaN    NaN  ...  20\n   0,5\n  10\n

[13 rows x 13 columns]
['Rang', 'Joueur', 'Équipe', 'Détail par édition', 'Matchs', 'Ratio', 'Buts']

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `pandas.read_html`:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_buteurs_de_la_Coupe_du_monde_de_football"

df = pd.read_html(url)[1]
df["Ratio"] = df["Buts"] / df["Matchs"]
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
    Édition               Joueur                Équipe  Matchs     Ratio  Buts
0      1930    Guillermo Stábile             Argentine       4  2.000000     8
1      1934      Oldřich Nejedlý       Tchécoslovaquie       4  1.250000     5
2      1938             Leônidas                Brésil       4  1.750000     7
3      1950               Ademir                Brésil       6  1.333333     8
4      1954        Sándor Kocsis               Hongrie       5  2.200000    11
5      1958        Just Fontaine                France       6  2.166667    13
6      1962       Flórián Albert               Hongrie       3  1.333333     4
7      1962            Garrincha                Brésil       6  0.666667     4
8      1962      Valentin Ivanov      Union soviétique       4  1.000000     4
9      1962      Dražan Jerković           Yougoslavie       6  0.666667     4
10     1962       Leonel Sánchez                 Chili       6  0.666667     4
11     1962                 Vavá                Brésil       6  0.666667     4
12     1966              Eusébio              Portugal       6  1.500000     9
13     1970          Gerd Müller  Allemagne de l’Ouest       6  1.666667    10
14     1974        Grzegorz Lato               Pologne       7  1.000000     7
15     1978         Mario Kempes             Argentine       7  0.857143     6
16     1982          Paolo Rossi                Italie       7  0.857143     6
17     1986         Gary Lineker            Angleterre       5  1.200000     6
18     1990  Salvatore Schillaci                Italie       7  0.857143     6
19     1994         Oleg Salenko                Russie       3  2.000000     6
20     1994    Hristo Stoitchkov              Bulgarie       7  0.857143     6
21     1998          Davor Šuker               Croatie       7  0.857143     6
22     2002              Ronaldo                Brésil       7  1.142857     8
23     2006       Miroslav Klose             Allemagne       7  0.714286     5
24     2010         Diego Forlán               Uruguay       7  0.714286     5
25     2010        Thomas Müller             Allemagne       6  0.833333     5
26     2010      Wesley Sneijder              Pays-Bas       7  0.714286     5
27     2010          David Villa               Espagne       7  0.714286     5
28     2014      James Rodríguez              Colombie       5  1.200000     6
29     2018           Harry Kane            Angleterre       6  1.000000     6
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]